# How can I make a POST request in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I created a website where I used JS and jQuery to send data to a server.
But now I am making that website as an app on my phone using react native.
I've read about the fetch function but I don't completely understand how I would go about it to make this request.
This is the code I used on my website:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).attr('id');
    pin: p
    $.get("http://192.168.0.129:80/", {
    pin: p
    });
    DisableButtons();
});
```

Right now I have the following:

```
sendData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var p = data;
    pin: p
    $.get("http://192.168.0.129:80/", {   --> this needs to be changed so it could work 
    pin: p                                    in react native 
    }); 
  }
```

So what I want  to accomplish is to send this url when I call the function: http://192.168.0.129/?pin=xxx

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the specific issue? Is there something in the [RN docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) or the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) that doesn't make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure where I should put the pin: p, would it be in body the first parameter?

Comment: Can you just try it? The `fetch` docs are pretty clear (IMO, anyway :) regarding parameters, as are the jQuery docs—it’s not clear what specifically you’re having a problem with.

Comment: Well I tried it, I got this:
const dataToSend = {pin: data};
    fetch('http://192.168.0.129:80/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/urlencoded'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    });

But it doesnt work...
It makes connection with the server but the data isn't send the same way as the website sends it.

Comment: Your title specifically asks about a `GET` request, but it looks like the code you're trying is a `POST` request.

Comment: Yup ,I'm still a little confused about the js code, because I do $.get() and therefore I think it's a GET request but it isn't?

Comment: Pretty sure it is; that's what `$.get` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical fetch request in javascript looks like this.

```
const sendData = async(data) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.0.129:80/?pin=${p}`).then(res => res.json()) //or res.text() if you are expecting text response.
    console.log('results')

}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would've worked aswell!

Comment: If you are using an async function there is no need to use "then"

Comment: it's not about "need", it's about writing the `res.json()` in a single line. You can also write a customised fetch in a separate function so you do not need to write a `await response.json()` code.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the solution, it was simpler then I thought:

```
sendData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var url = `http://192.168.0.129:80/?pin=${data}`;
    fetch(url);
  }
```

Comment: This seems like a GET request your making with query params

Comment: I am realy confused, I know GET is to ask for data and POST is to send data but you can send data with a GET request?

Comment: Yes.
Please have a look at MDN doc here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.
You'll find out more about 'method' argument that can be passed in order to perform 'POST' request with fetch ('GET' being the default mode)